# Websocket server connection

Tags: php, networking, websocket

I want to make a server with websocket. I've tried a lot of programming language (python, php, c++, etc.), and everything seems okay as far as I connect to it as ws://127.0.0.1:12345. But if I try to change the address to the IP of my PC (89.135.123.456), then I can't connect to the server. The server is always binded to the IP 0.0.0.0, the port 12345 is enabled in my router. I can connect to the xampp server by using my IP adress. What's the reason I can't connect to it with my IP adress?

Comment: ....456 cannot be your ip but if you have just hidden real IP then it's ok. try to just telnet to your IP at the port. also check your firewall settings.

Comment: x.x.123.456, yes, it's not a real ip. :D

Comment: have you checked your firewall settings(if you have one)? you will need to add exception to accept incoming connection from your router. Your apache server will be having this exception added to the firewall. use that for reference.

Comment: I always enable the server program on the firewall.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are developing on your local machine which is connected to the internet via a common router with network address translation (NAT).

Binding the server to 0.0.0.0 makes sure that the process is listening on all interfaces, that's required and you have it, good.

From where did you try to connect to your WebSocket server when using the external IP address? You can't use that one in your local network or even on localhost when you are behind a typical NATed internet connection. When you try to connect to your server from a different machine within the local network, you need to use the local IP address.

If you try to connect from "the outside", i.e. from the internet side of your router using the external IP address of your router, then you need to make sure that a port-forward is configured in your router: any IP packet with target `your_external_ip:ws_port` needs to be forwarded to `your_local_ip:ws_port`. Otherwise the router simply drops the incoming packet, because it is unexpected.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/Ifyz4DK.png
I'm trying to connect to the server from my PC as my IP address (but only "localhost:12345" works). But my friend from an other city can't connect to it as 89.135.123.456:12345.

Comment: However he can connect to my apache server from his browser (http:// 89.135.123.456).

Comment: Try the "virtual servers" section and make sure to forward to *your* machine in the local network.

Comment: OK, if `192.168.1.1` is your internal IP address, this is all you need. Delete the corresponding entry from your port triggering menu. In order to further debug this issue the next step would be to see if packets sent from the outside to your external_ip:12345 arrive at your local machine @ `192.168.1.1` at all. On Linux, you can use `netstat`, `tcpdump`, `wireshark` for this. On Windows, use the monitoring function of your firewall and/or the Windows resource monitor. You should also consider upvoting/accepting my answer, it is correct in principle -- the rest is debugging on your side.